# How to convert arulesViz plot to htmlwidget in R

Tags: r, arules

We are using **aluresViz** package of R. This package provide a function **plot()**. the function has argument **interactive = TRUE** ,which make it interactive so we want to convert this interactive into html widget .Here we use this method..it not working.

```
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(p, plotlyoutput, selfcontained = FALSE)
```

Example:
as a image it work
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# save a plot as a html page
p <- plotly_arules(rules)
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(p, "arules.html", selfcontained = FALSE)
browseURL("arules.html")

# interactive matrix visualization
plotly_arules(rules, method = "matrix")
```